# Javascript library to collect objects properties, do batch processing and map results back to objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

For array of objects:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "test", tagId: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "test", tagId: 15},
    {id: 3, name: "test", tagId: 5},
]
```

Need to reduce list of specific properties (tagId) to unique array [1,15,5], call some batch processing method, for example, doing http request for API for list of entities:

```
async (ids) => await axios.get('http://apihost/tag', {id: ids})
```

For result array of objects:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "tag1"},
    {id: 15, name: "tag2"},
    {id: 5, name: "tag3"},
]
```

Finally need to map this objects by ID attribute to original array of objects matching by result.id => original.tagId, in fact doing an SQL join of two arrays to get this (like https://github.com/mtraynham/lodash-joins):

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "test", tagId: 1, tag: {id: 1, name: "tag1"}},
    {id: 2, name: "test", tagId: 15, tag: {id: 15, name: "tag2"}},
    {id: 3, name: "test", tagId: 5, tag: {id: 5, name: "tag3"}},
]
```

I'm already wrote a PHP library for this with API like:

```
new BulkMap(source).map(
  'tagId',
  'tag',
  async (ids) => axios.get('http://apihost/tag', {id: ids})
);
```

But now i need this in JS. Is there any Javascript/NodeJS library to do so? It looks like pretty common used pattern for microservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like @RiverTam solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629965/962746. The only thing to fix is: multiple objects in source array can have the same tagId, so i'm index response objects instead of source objects:

```
const lodashUniq = require('lodash.uniq');
const lodashMap = require('lodash.map');

const source = [
    {id: 1, name: "test", tagId: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "test", tagId: 15},
    {id: 3, name: "test", tagId: 5},
];

const uniqueIds = lodashUniq(lodashMap(source, 'tagId'));
const tags = await axios.get('http://apihost/tag', { id: uniqueIds });

const tagsIndex = new Map(tags.map(tag => [tag.id, tag]));
const result = source.map(s => (
    {... s, tag: tagsIndex.get(s.tagId)}
));
```

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach.

```
const { map, uniq } = require('lodash/fp');

const arr = /* you say you already have this */;

const uniqueIds = uniq(map('tagId', arr));
const objects = await axios.get('http://apihost/tag', { id: uniqueIds });
const associated = arr.map(({ id, tagId, name }) => (
  { id, tagId, name, tag: objects.find(o => o.id === tagId) };
));
```

If you want to index (which may avoid an O(N^2) solution)

```
const byTagId = new Map();
arr.forEach(o => byTagId.set(o.tagId, o));
const objects = await axios.get('http://apihost/tag', { id: byTagId.keys() });
const associated = arr.map(({ id, tagId, name }) => (
  { id, tagId, name, tag: byTagId.get(tagId) }
));
```

Comment: Not so good to have find inside map. Mind source array can contain 5k objects. Need to build index, like lodash-joins do.

Comment: Thank you for show how to call lodash.map with 'tagId', don't know this.

Comment: np. keep in mind that only works like that with lodash/fp. lodash proper will have the arguments reversed: `map(arr, 'tagId')`

Comment: It is even better to use Map because instead of uniq+map can use byTagId.keys() to have unique IDs.

Comment: Index Map may be created as `const byTagId = new Map(arr.map(o => [o.tagId, o]));` instead of arr.forEach.

Comment: @MikhailElfimov You will find that this performs worse. It is more functional, but you are creating N more elements which will take O(N) time as well as O(N) space (albeit temporarily). The `.forEach` approach will be more performant in all regards.

Comment: Multiple objects in source array can have the same tagId, so it is better to index results, really.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.Here is my attempt.

```
const inits = [
    {id: 1, name: "test", tagId: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "test", tagId: 15},
    {id: 3, name: "test", tagId: 5},
];

// Get all ids
const ids = inits.map(init => init.tagId);

const results = [
    {id: 1, name: "tag1"},
    {id: 15, name: "tag2"},
    {id: 5, name: "tag3"},
];

// Add results to object
const final = inits.map(init => {
    init.tag = results.find(res => res.id === init.tagId);
    return init;
});
```

[Updated]

If you can be certain order of the objects will remain the same, you can speed it up:

```
// Add results to object
const final = inits.map((init, index) => {
    init.tag = results.[index];
    return init;
});
```

Why is JavaScript so sexy :(

Comment: Not so good to have find inside map. Mind source array can contain 5k objects. Need to build index.

Comment: Any way, question is not to implement this, but to find existing npm package before write own.

Comment: I doubt there will be a better implementation even in a library

Comment: You can speed it up if you are always certain order of the object will remain the same. Then you just assign first to first, second to second and so on..

Comment: @ClintonYeboah That would be the ideal speed, but if you don't know the order will be the same, you can use a `Map` to index and achieve an O(N) solution rather than O(N^2) as you will with the inner `.find` solution

Comment: Order is not guarantied to be preserved.

Comment: @RiverTam yeah right. You know I completely forgot n+n < n*n :(